# Cystal Report: Migrating project from vs 2005 to vs 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am trying to migrate a project that worked on crystal report 10.2.36 to VS 2012. I am getting an error that the 10.2.36 assemblies cannot be loaded. I tried installing crystal reports for vs2012 but many syntax errors inside my code appeared.

What is the right way to build this project on vs2012 and .net 2.0 platform.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem could be related to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794679/satellite-assembly-always-targets-version-4-0 ...Satellite assemblies compiled by VS2012 or VS2013 ignore the setting of requested target .NET framework version 2.0 and always target .NET 4.0. Then these satellite assemblies cannot be loaded by the main assembly targeting .NET 2.0. The example of satellite assemblies are localization assemblies.